# Laravel/MySQL: Increment StoreOrderNumber based on StoreGuid

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I have an orders table with primary key `OrderGuid`. This is a 32-bit unique identifier that is used by many parts of the system to track the order.

It is unfortunately not the nicest looking piece of data and so it has been decided that we will need a `StoreOrderNumber` field. This will be a unique integer for each `StoreGuid` in the orders tables. It also needs to be auto incrementing e.g. the first order added to the table for a given `StoreGuid` will be given a `StoreOrderNumber` of 1, the next 2, then 3 etc. Every order for a certain `StoreGuid` will follow the same numbering for the `StoreOrderNumber` i.e. starting at 1, then 2, 3, 4...

I've totally drawn a blank on how I might do this in Laravel and MySQL. There is an increments option that can be added to a field in a table, but this does not take into consideration that we only need to increment for each new order for a particular `StoreGuid`.

```
+-----------+-----------+------------------+
| OrderGuid | StoreGuid | StoreOrderNumber |
+-----------+-----------+------------------+
| aaa111    | abc123    |                1 |
| bbb222    | abc123    |                2 |
| ccc333    | xyz789    |                1 |
| ddd444    | xyz789    |                2 |
| eee555    | abc123    |                3 |
| fff666    | xyz789    |                3 |
+-----------+-----------+------------------+
```

Comment: I don't clearly understand your problem, but i think, that laravel mutators can solve your problem: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator You can add logic for specified model element (column) e.g. select max value for provided conditionals and then set value + 1 for this element.

Comment: example table added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a MySQL `TRIGGER`.

Something like this (untested, but gets the idea across):

```
CREATE TRIGGER SetStoreOrderNumber BEFORE INSERT ON Orders
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.StoreOrderNumber = (
        SELECT (COALESCE(MAX(StoreOrderNumber), 0) + 1
        FROM Orders
        WHERE Orders.StoreGuid = NEW.StoreGuid
    );
END
```

The `COALESCE` is necessary to allow creating the first order in a new store, because `MAX(StoreOrderNumber)` will be `NULL`.

Comment: Ah yes! Triggers! I remember them now. Will give it a go and let you know. Thanks.